# Convert timestamp into time()

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I want to convert a timestamp from mysql to format as time().

IF i have this date:

```
2015-06-05 08:53:30
```

I wants to convert to something like: `1433491545`

I have to use the method date() ?

I cant found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `strtotime()` -

```
strtotime("2015-06-05 08:53:30");
```

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)